# How to print a matrices using cat in R

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices in my functions names as `newpar`. I would like to use `cat` function to print the this list. However, I have got a vector instead of matrix.

Here is my code:

```
 for(i in 1:2)
newpar <- list()
newpar[[i]]<- matrix(0,5,5)

for ( i in 1:2) {
  cat(newpar[[i]], "\t")
}
```

The output is this:
    `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

I would like the output to be as a matrix.

When I use `print` function, I have got `NULL` for the first matrix. 
How can I solve my problem? any help, please?

Comment: you got null as you set `newpar <- list()` after running `newpar[[1]]` . Change your initla loop to `newpar <- vector("list", length=2); for(i in 1:2) { ;  newpar[[i]]<- matrix(0,5,5) ; }`

Comment: You are recreating the list each time through the loop, destroying what was there in the previous iterations: put `newpar <- list()` before the loop. And use `"\n"`, not `"\t"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas with `cat` I still got a vector not a matrix. However, `print` solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas

Comment: Thanks @user20650

Answer (score 1):

you can create a list of matrices with lapply

```
    > newpar=lapply(1:2,function(x) matrix(0,5,5) )
> newpar
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: My function in very large. So through the iteration of my function, I would like to print the matrices for each iteration. That is what I need to use cat or print.

Comment: From `cat` documentation: Currently only atomic vectors and names are handled. You can also check here http://www.studytrails.com/r/core/r_console_printing/ where they mention the same thing. I believe you should go with `print` if you want to display the matrix in a 'matrix format'